# python 3 How to let the user input name and Caeser Cipher the result?

Tags: python-3.x, function, input, caesar-cipher

I'm very new to Python here but I'm slowly learning the ropes! I want to make a program where the user can input, let's say their name, and get their name returned with an asterisk between every letter. I'm having trouble understanding how to type in an input. This is what I've done so far:

```
def fancy_print(s, join_char='-'):
    letters = list(s)
    output = join_char + join_char.join(letters) + join_char
    print(output)

fancy_print("PYTHON", "*")
```

So, as you can see, I can write the code down in the program, but I haven't worked out how to get the user to input the word that i want written like that. For example:
Program: 
"Enter your name:
User: Joel
Program returns:
 J * o * e * l "

I thought it also would be cool to have ANOTHER function that would have sort of a caesar cipher function. So the program would push every letter, let's say one step, in the alphabet. So it would return: "Your name ciphered would be KPFM"

I hope my question makes sense. As I said, I'm new to this. English also isn't my first language so go ahead and edit and/or ask questions if you like. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like homework!? ;)

Comment: @fast Got the idea from an online course, (that didn't really get me any 'credentials' or anything). Not taking that online course anymore though, since I didn't like it too much. Have been playing around a bit with codeacademy instead, which I like better.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get input from a user, you should use the input method from python standard library and assign it to variable. So, your code can be re-written as

```
def fancy_print(s, join_char='-'):
    letters = list(s)
    output = join_char + join_char.join(letters) + join_char
    print(output)


name = input("your name")
fancy_print(name, "*")
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you! Of course... I wrote the input in the wrong place all along.